# Object not deleting using remove in Enity Framework

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

hi i want to remove row from database using entity framework but i have little bit problem that from first table it's deleting data but from second it's not deleting even not showing any error but don't know why it's not deleting data from another table which is foreign key.
Even no eror but when i saw in database organization row succesfully deleted but from institute it's not deleting any one know doing anything wrong.

here is my code;

```
public static bool DeleteOrganization(int OrganizationID)
        {
            Organization Org = Db.Organizations.First(x => x.ORG_ID == OrganizationID);
            Institute Ins = Db.Institutes.First(x => x.INS_FK_ORGID == OrganizationID);

            try
            {
                Db.Organizations.Remove(Org);
                Db.Institutes.Remove(Ins);
                return true;
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that data from first table is deleted?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Berezovskiy yes i have checked as well in second For institute it's getting correct object according to INS_FK_ORGID but not deleting don't know why

Comment: Strange - you are not calling `Db.SaveChanges()` anywhere

Comment: when iam calling Db.savechanges() then it's showing me error just when i am removing elements. error:- after apply DB.savechanges()
getting this error if iam using Db.save changes
Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Comment: Is it your real code? Do you have some modifications of Org and Ins before you remove them?

Comment: no i it's pure deleting function n real code and i am not doing any modification before just passing organization id through this id doing remove.

Comment: Where is Db defined? I noticed that your method is static, and if you are using a static database connection you could have some major issues with thread-safety.

Answer (score 0):

You should post Error in here, may be i can help you fix it =))
I did fix bug for you by add _context.SaveChanges(); after changes object
exp:

```
ESPrivilege obj = new ESPrivilege();
                obj.Id = id[i];
                _context.ESPrivileges.Attach(obj);
                _context.ESPrivileges.Remove(obj);
                _context.SaveChanges();
```